# How much can we estimate the constant in Harnack’s inequality

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I’ve just seen a theorem about the constant without proof which is:

(DeGiorgi-Nash-Moser Interior Harnack inequality).
Let v be a non-negative solution of

$$Lu=div(A(x)\nabla u)=0$$

in $B_1$, then for r < 1

$$sup_{B_r} u ≤ c(1 − r)^{-p} inf_{B_r} u$$

with c,p depending only on n and λ. (For r close to one, we may choose the constant c
equal to one by making p large.)

I DO know how to prove it for Laplacian and when it comes to the general elliptic equations I tried to use the weak Harnack’s inequality but I find it’s kind of hard to calculate the constant and didn’t come up with a complete proof. Is there any reference I should read? Moreover, I’m now confused with another question——How much is the constant combined with the shape of the subset V? I do think that there are some results about it, but I don’t know where to learn it.

Comment: About the weak Harnack I determine $\tau=\frac{1+\theta}{2}$ and wish to get that C is bounded by a polynomial of $1-\tau$, but I couldn’t finish it because I get a little confused about the constant in J-N’s lemme

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, by I suggest that you give it some more time here and, in case there are no answers, post it on MathOverflow. If you do so, I will be most grateful if you can let me know with a comment here.

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso Thank you for your advice. I do think that I’ve made the proof of the polynomial estimate but I didn’t come up with anything about the constant for the subset of some other shape. I think I should give it some more time here.